# Running a bot with pm2 breaks paths to local files

Tags: node.js

I have a telegram bot (using telegraf) that listens to chats and replies with local files. This when run with "node index.js" works, but with pm2 files aren't sent.

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf');

const extra = require('telegraf/extra');
const markup = extra.markdown();

const token = TOKEN;
const bot = new Telegraf(token);



bot.hears(['/cal'], (ctx) => {
    ctx.replyWithPhoto({ source: './cal.jpg' });
});


bot.hears(['/42'], (ctx) => {
    ctx.replyWithPhoto({ source: './42.jpg' });
});
```

There are no changes other than what I use to execute it. The files I want to send are in the same folder of the index.js file.

Answer (score 1):

Try by resolving the full path name :

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf');
const path = require('path');
const extra = require('telegraf/extra');
const markup = extra.markdown();

const token = TOKEN;
const bot = new Telegraf(token);



bot.hears(['/cal'], (ctx) => {
    ctx.replyWithPhoto({ source: path.resolve('./cal.jpg') });
});


bot.hears(['/42'], (ctx) => {
    ctx.replyWithPhoto({ source: path.resolve('./42.jpg') });
});
```

Comment: That was a nice try, I really thought this would fix it, but it didn't.

Comment: It did show me the error! Executing it with pm2 changed the path to /home/user. I didn't know that, but now I can fix it. Is there a way to make the path the actual project path without hard-coding the full path?